# Why does C# allow Inner/Nested Scope in Methods

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, scope

I am wondering why C# allows nested/inner scopes for functions.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
        public int InnerScopeMethod()
    {
        int i = 10;

        //Inner Scope
        {               
            int j = 100;//j will not work outside of the scope.
            i *= j;
        }//Scope Ends Here

    //j = 10 /// This Will Cause Error.
        return i;
    }
```

As you can see the method body has an anonymous or unnamed scope and it is legal in C# 4.

I want to know why is it here? Is this just for providing small scopes for variables or it has other uses?

Comment: I guess it is not only legal in C# 4, but also available in previous versions or even available in most of the languages like C. What's your catch by the way. Can you be more brief about this?

Comment: I just want to know what is the purpose for this kind of scopes

Comment: Note that many people will also refer to this as "nested" scope. As regards your question, it's a bit like asking, "Why do I have a wrench in my toolbox?" with the answer being that it's useful when I need to use it.

Comment: scopes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It (usually at least) isn't necessary to do this in C#, but then (as Brandon Moore said), why not?

One reason could be that certain variables only have a limited time where they are valid, and by putting that variable inside a scope, you make sure that noone can accidentally use them later.

Additionally, C# is based on C, where this construct is very useful. In C, variables can only be declared at the start of a scope, so something like what you wrote can be done in long methods if you only need a temporary variable at one place (ex. a loop index).

Comment: It is not quiet right to say "In C, variables can only be declared at the start of a scope" that might be true for some/older versions but is not true for every c version/compiler [example](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44rM69EITcxM09DU6GaixPEK0ssMlSwVTAysObiLCgCiqRpKEHFVFNi8pR0wCo0gbLFyYl5QEnVFKCYGkwQrxa4DUZAKWO8Nhhhs8FIk5CW2v//zcy4LC0B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

The question should be why "wouldn't" it be there?  In other words, what purpose would you have for using the curly braces like that unless you wanted to have an inner scope?  And if there is an inner scope for all other constructs that use curly braces (i.e. any kind of loop or using statement) then why wouldn't using curly braces by themselves have the same effect?

Edit:  I think your real question though is: "Is there ever a time that I would 'want' to do this?"

As far as my personal experience goes the answer would be no.  But that doesn't mean that they should go out of their way to prohibit this functionality that already exists (due to its existing use with various constructs) just because I will never use it.

Answer (score 0):

So this kind of thing probably seems useless to object oriented programmers who are used to very small, single responsibility functions that provide a limited enough scope for all their local variables.

For procedural programming, however, being able to limit the scope of some variables in one part of a very long function is very helpful, as it helps you to avoid having too many local variables in the same scope that could lead to errors if you accidentally use the wrong one or run into naming conflicts, etc.