# Do Inner or Nested Scopes in C# influence the GC?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, scoping

Refering to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455504/inner-nested-scope-in-methods) as an example, do inner / nested scoping influence the GC or memory management in any way? Comming from a c++ or c standpoint anything declared and instanciated in the function that is not referenced anywhere else or declared outside of the defining scope is usually freed up after the function has dropped out of scope. Does the GC do something similar in this case? Does GC consider these inner scopes? Other than preventing declarations from being accessed outside of the scope, I dont see anything else that this feature provides.

Comment: With "usually freed up" you mean, it's usually manually freed up by the programmer. The only similar thing you do, is calling Dispose to clean up. Everything else is done automatically, but you have no influence on when it is done.

Comment: @Holger well specifically you can define an object on the stack just by calling the constructor without the *new* instruction. Which would drop the memory used by that constructed object once the instanciating function goes out of scope or off the execution stack. If you did a *new* with an object in c++ in a function scope you would have a definate memory leak because you blatantly need to free it as you just put it on the heap. That in itself is expensive so generally anything created in a function that isnt needed else where shouldnt be put on the heap just for the liftime of that function.

Comment: But the GC and the stack have nothing to do with each other. The stack only holds values, or references to instances.Without "new" you can only create value types and only on the stack. This is "destroyed" if they run out of scope, but this is not managed memory. There is no difference to C++, an "int i" is in both cases is allocating stack memory, without a "new", and you never had to care for destruction. objects are only created with 'new', and as soon as all references run out of scope, they are signaled "ready to be deleted", but you have no control when they are deleted.

Comment: A memory leak in C# is defined as, after a GC happened, some objects that you don't need any more, are not removed/deleted from the managed memory. So the leak most often means "some variable is holding a reference to this object, and you have to find out where and how and why this reference is still stored".
You are forced to put instances of classes on the heap. There is no way around.

Comment: Vanilla C++ has no notion of a GC. Not unless you roll your own or use a memory management library. Nearest you'll get is smart pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we're just talking about reference types:

> do inner / nested scoping influence the GC or memory management in any way?

In Release: no, they do not. The GC doesn't care about the scope of your local variables: it cares about when the local variable was last referenced. Letting the variable go out of scope, or assigning `null` to it, does nothing.

This is why [`GC.KeepAlive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.keepalive?view=netframework-4.8) exists.

In Debug: local variables will be kept alive for the duration of the method to aid debugging, regardless of scope.

> Other than preventing declarations from being accessed outside of the scope, I dont see anything else that this feature provides.

That's pretty much it. It's rare to see inner scopes which are just for scoping in C#.

Comment: Scope plays no role in the Debug build either.  Most obvious way to see that is that IL has no notion of scope.  Lifetime is extended to the end of the method.

Comment: @HansPassant So it doesn't. I assumed it would re-use local slots if the variables they were used for were in separate scopes, but it seems it doesn't. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant Actually, variable lifetime is communicated by the JIT to the GC, and isn't represented in IL, IIRC (yes you've got local slots, but this lifetime information is more specific than that). Is it definitely true that in Debug, the JIT tells the GC that all locals are in scope for the entire method, regardless of any extra scopes

Answer (score 0):

In C# as well as C++ the GC has usually not much to do with it.

Scopes usually lay on the stack wich is not managed by the GC at all.
This behavior only differs for lambdas, if you refer to the outer scope from a lambda an object is created for the scopes variables and that object can get cleaned up by the GC when the lambda code is left.

> The garbage collector uses the following information to determine
>   whether objects are live:
>
> Stack roots. Stack variables provided by the just-in-time (JIT)
>   compiler and stack walker. JIT optimizations can lengthen or shorten
>   regions of code within which stack variables are reported to the
>   garbage collector.
>
> Garbage collection handles. Handles that point to managed objects and
>   that can be allocated by user code or by the common language runtime.
>
> Static data. Static objects in application domains that could be
>   referencing other objects. Each application domain keeps track of its
>   static objects.

For more details see: [Fundamentals of garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

And for Lambdas: [Local functions compared to lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/local-functions-vs-lambdas)

Comment: The GC absolutely does manage objects which are referenced by variables on the stack

Comment: but GC only cares about objects and references. of cause the variables on the stack can contain references, but otherwise scopes are unrelated to objects. basically for the GC the stack is only an *Application Root*

Comment: Yes, the stack is an object root. But those are roots to objects which the GC manages. You can have a scope containing reference types, which is on the stack, and those references are roots of objects which the GC manages. The GC does care about those references

Comment: Well as I understood his question he was kinda asking if the GC reacts to scopes. And it does not, not in C# and not in C++. It only considers the stack as a root when it is already running. And even if there is no reference to this objects left, they might already be in second generation and not be collected in the next GC run. So they are not necessarily collected when so scope is left like he asked.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Value Types still are cleaned up.

With reference types it is more complicated. References run out of scope, but the GC is responsible for cleaning up the instances themself - eventually. See, running the GC is costly. While it Collects and Finalizes, every other thread in this Application **must** pause.

As a result, the GC is lazy with running. If it only runs once - on application closure - that is the ideal case. Beyond that only a special GC strategy, explicit calls of GC.Collect() (wich you should not have in production code) or the danger of a OutOfMemory exception will get it running.

When it runs, all that maters for each and every instance is "do I have a unbroken chain of references to a application root?" How long ago it ran out of scope does not mater (except for Optimsations like Generation Systems).

Do note that sometimes you have to do some cleanup work when a unmanaged resource runs out of scope/right now. That is what Finalizers, iDisposeable and using blocks handle.

Comment: "*Beyond that only a special GC strategy, explicit calls of GC.Collet (wich you should not have in production code) or the danger of a OutOfMemory exception will get it running.*" -- this is not true. For example, the GC will be triggered if an allocation budget is exceeded

Comment: @canton7 Would that allocation budget issue cause a "OutOfMemory" Exception if it is not resolved? If yes, then I already said that. If not, what does it do? It has to be handeled some way.

Comment: No, it would not. The allocation budget is per-generation, and is dynamically updated as the GC learns your application's allocation patterns. It is significantly less than the total amount of available memory: gen0 starts at a few kB/MB IIRC. The book "Pro .NET Memory Management" goes into lots of detail. The GC will run frequently during application startup, and usually during normal operation. See in particular the AllocSmall ETW event

Comment: @canton7 Those Generations are a concept that only applies to the GC. If it maters, the GC is running already. And "Pro .NET Memory Management" does imply that it might only apply with one of those alternative GC strategies I mentioned.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're trying to say. It's not clear what you mean by "*special GC strategy*" -- do you mean "normal GC operation"? My point was that it's very very normal for the GC to do collections, without `GC.Collect` being called or the system running out of memory